# Query Optimization for EF Query

Tags: sql, performance, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core to perform a complex query. I need to use `group by` and pick the top result from the group and then perform filter on the top rows of each group.

When I use EF profiler, it shows that query fetched 21647 rows and the final result after the filter is 28. I assume that EF uses the where query after retrieving the columns from DB.

Here is the structure of query.

```
private IQueryable<long> GetAssignedIds(int? lpId = null, int? customerTenantId = null)
{
    var islpAdmin = _permissionChecker.IsGranted(AppPermissions.Pages_PP_lpAdmin);
    var query = (
        from -------QUERY--------------------
        join -------QUERY--------------------
        join -------QUERY--------------------
        join -------QUERY--------------------
        select new
        {
            -----SELECT VARIABLES----------
        })
        .OrderBy(c => c.Priority)
        .GroupBy(c => new { c.ScpId, c.OrderId })
        .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault())
        .WhereIf(lpId.HasValue, c => c.lpId == lpId)
        .WhereIf(islpAdmin, c => c.lpId == currentTenantId)
        .WhereIf(!islpAdmin, c => c.eId == currentTenantId)
        .Select(c => c.ScoId)
        .Distinct();
}
```

How can I optimize this query? I know `.Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault())` is the problem here but I'm not able to find proper alternative here.

Comment: which version of EF Core are you using? prior to 2.1 Group By was always executed in memory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation

Comment: I'm afraid EF Core still (even latest 2.1.2) is not good for (can't translate to SQL) such type of queries.

Comment: I'm using the latest release of EF Core i.e. 2.1.1

Comment: Can someone provide me raw SQL query for this? :)